# Icons misaligned

Tags: css, antd

After updating to antd 3.10 I'v noticed many of my icons are now misaligned:

[image]

Not sure why this is happening, I'v disabled all css besides antd.css but it's happening, even on a blank page (not necessarily in a modal).

Thing is I cannot reproduce this in a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/kw7nrzo9w7) with the same version, i've inspected everything in the browser inspector to check all the styles being applied and everything seems the same, and I am all out of troubleshooting idea.

Any ideas as to what could have caused this?

Update:
I rolled back to antd 3.0.0 and everything is fine. It definitely something has to do with the new svg icons. I still cannot replicate this outside of my environment. I am very much still interested in a solution to this.

Comment: checked that codesandbox link. it looks fine to me on chrome browser, in which browser do you find that issue?

Comment: As I said, I'm not able to reproduces this, that code pen is just a reference to what I am doing. I'm not sure how else I can present this honestly.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. The icons inside the message component don't show up at all. Downgrading to 3.7.3 fixed the issue. This is blocking me from upgrading.

Comment: @RyanWarner Can I see your webpack config? If it can't be reproduced in a fresh environment, then maybe there's some common denominator there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with webpack config - you need to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page. This is also why you can't reproduce it in codepen - doctype is specified even inside sandbox frame there.

Comment: Wow, over a year later, you the mvp arrgh